# Notation conventions for subsets of widely used sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I want to express "$x$ is rational and not equal to $0$"

$x\neq 0 \in \mathbb{Q}$ seems awkward to me since $x\neq 0$ is a logical statement, not a rational number. Options I can think of include:
$$x\in \mathbb{Q} \setminus 0$$
$$x\in \mathbb{Q} \land x \neq 0$$
$$x \in \mathbb{Q} | x\neq 0$$

Is there a standard convention? I'm trying to develop a sensible, standard notation to use amongst my classes.

Comment: For this particular question, I'd use $x\in \mathbb Q^*$ since $\mathbb Q^*$, the multiplicative group of the rationals, already means all non-zero rationals.  If, say, you wanted to express "$x$ is rational and $x\neq 3$ "  then I'd use $x\in \mathbb Q\,|\,x\neq 3$.

Comment: As a rule thumb I avoid symbols unless it makes the content more readable or is useful for calculation. In this case I would express it as "$a$ is a rational and non-zero" almost always. If I had to symbolize it I would use the first or second form of but written as "$x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $x \neq 0$"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One alternative notation you can use is
$$x\in \mathbb Q^\times.$$
Here $\mathbb Q^\times$ denotes all elements of $\mathbb Q$ which are invertible in $\mathbb Q$. Since $\mathbb Q$ is a field, this is all non-zero elements of $\mathbb Q$. However be aware that this is not *always* equal to the set without zero; for example $\mathbb Z^\times = \{-1,1\}$ because for any other $n\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$, $\frac{1}{n}\notin\mathbb Z$.

Yet another not uncommon notation writes the inequality without the leading $x$ as index, that is,
$$x\in\mathbb Q_{\ne 0}.$$
This notation has the advantage that it works also for a whole bunch of other sets, like $\mathbb R_{<0}$ for the negative real numbers, $\mathbb Q_{\ge 0}$ for the nonnegative rational numbers or $\mathbb Z_{>42}$ for the integers larger than $42$.

However if only a single number is excluded, I personally would prefer the notation
$$x\in\mathbb Q\setminus\{0\}$$
(note the braces around $0$, which are missing in your post). At least in cases where I explicitly would use formulas; otherwise I'd just write:

> $x$ is a non-zero rational number.

Answer (score 3):

$x\in \mathbb{Q} \setminus \{0\}$

Answer (score 3):

Two of your four suggestions are simply incorrect, one might be understood but is at best highly non-standard, and one is correct.

- $x\ne 0\in\Bbb Q$ says that $x\ne 0$ and $0\in\Bbb Q$, which is not what you want to say. It **would** be correct to say $0\ne x\in\Bbb Q$, and that construction is sometimes used.
- $x\in\Bbb Q\setminus 0$ is meaningless (unless you’re doing set theory and using $0$ for the empty set, in which case it just says that $x$ is rational); what you mean here is presumably $x\in\Bbb Q\setminus\{0\}$, i.e., $x$ is a member of $\Bbb Q$ but not a member of $\{0\}$.
- $x\in\Bbb Q\mid x\ne 0$ would probably be understood, but it’s out of place except in the definition of the set $\Bbb Q\setminus\{0\}$ as $\{x\in\Bbb Q\mid x\ne 0\}$; the vertical bar simply isn’t normally used that way. Moreover, in some contexts (e.g., formal grammars) the vertical bar is equivalent to logical $\lor$, so for people used to those contexts this could be genuinely confusing.
- $x\in\Bbb Q\land x\ne 0$ is notationally correct. In general, however, I think that using words instead of logical connectives ($x\in\Bbb Q\text{ and }x\ne 0$) makes such expressions a little easier to read.

In general I would write $x\in\Bbb Q\setminus\{0\}$: it says exactly what I want to say and does so completely unambiguously. A fairly common notation is $x\in\Bbb Q_{\ne 0}$, and in an algebraic setting you might see $x\in\Bbb Q^\times$, since $\Bbb Q^\times$ is a common notation for the multiplicative group of non-zero rationals.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that $x\ne0\in\Bbb Q$ should not be used. If anything, $0\ne x\in\Bbb Q$ would be more apt, and still I would not use it. $x\in\Bbb Q\setminus\{0\}$ is the way to go.
It should be pointed out that:

- no one will ever argue with (precise) plain writing in a discursive explanation, therefore "$x\in\Bbb Q$ and $x\ne0$" is just as good;
- if you have to write symbolically for any reason, you can use $x\in\Bbb Q\land x\ne 0$ or $x\in\Bbb Q\setminus\{0\}$ at leisure;
- the symbol "$\mid$" is synonymous with "such that" only when it is part of the set-builder notation $\{\bullet\mid \diamond\}$.

Answer (score 1):

- The first one is incorrect, but you can say $x\in\mathbb Q\setminus\{0\}$.
- The second is a bit too formal for me, I would just put a comma: $x\in\mathbb Q, x\ne 0$ or just use the word "and" ($x\in\mathbb Q$ and $x\ne 0$) - however, in the context where you explicitly want to involve logical operations in your curriculum, it is good in its original form.
- The third one (or the one where the vertical bar is replaced with a colon) is usually used in set definitions/building, e.g. $A:=\{x\in\mathbb Q|x\ne 0\}$ or $A:=\{x\in\mathbb Q:x\ne 0\}$ but I think it is awkward otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the first, but wrap the 0 in brackets to make it explicitly a set, probably not necessary technically, but easier to read.

Would avoid the third like a plague, may cause confusion in people more familiar with programming ( single vertical line is used as logical or in many languages)

even i read it as:  x is rational or x is nonzero. and do a double take, because that's just $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score -1):

Any set excluding $0$ is generally notated with a superscript asterisk.  This notation comes from [multiplicative groups](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultiplicativeGroup.html).

$$\Bbb Q\setminus\{0\} = \Bbb Q^*$$